# how do I isolate session (cookie and localstorage) in tab for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I tried to make chrome extension to isolate session, cookies and localstorage for each tab in chrome just like sessionbox. but How do they manage it to separate session each tab?

I've tried to call little api to store cookies each tab and put it back in chrome but it seems not like how sessionbox isolate their session. Do you have any idea how session in sessionbox works?

Comment: There's no such API in Chrome. You can imitate a new session by overriding cookies for all requests in that tab by using chrome.webRequest API. You can also inspect/debug the source code of that extension.

Comment: how do I inspect inspect/debug source code if it's webpacked.I tried reverse engineering but still don't get how do they manage isolation

Comment: If they don't have a source code repository then you'd have to reverse-engineer their minified code shipped in the extension.

Comment: @AriefGoldalworming, did you manage to do that?